# Facing on Make Like Unlike Button in php , mysql using ajax calling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I m creating like and unlike button for my website , at my local server i used seprate file it it working fine but when i install at my website then it is not working properly.

I m Fetching some information using this code from url bar

```
    <?php
    error_reporting (0);
    include "includes/session.php";

    include 'database/db.php';

    extract($_REQUEST);             
    if(isset($_GET["i"]))
    {
    $pid=($_GET['p']);
    $lid=($_GET['i']);
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    $likquery = mysql_query("select * from likes where userid=$id and postid=$lid");
    if(mysql_num_rows($likquery)==1){

    ?>
        <a class="unlike" id="<?php echo $lid ?>">UnLike</a>&nbsp;<span class="like_update" id="<?php echo $lid ?>"></span>

    <?php }else{?>

        <a class="like" id="<?php echo $lid ?>">Like</a>



        <?php 
    }?>
```

AFTER this I use script

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').on('click','.like',function(){


    var postId = $(this).attr('id');

    var postData = 'postid='+postId+'&uid=<?php echo $id ?>';

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "like_notes",
        data: postData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(){

            $('#'+postId).text('UnLike').addClass('unlike').removeClass('like');
        }

    });

    })



    $('body').on('click','.unlike',function(){

    var postId = $(this).attr('id');

    var postData = 'postid='+postId+'&uid=<?php echo $id ?>';

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "likeun_notes",
        data: postData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(){

            $('#'+postId).text('Like').addClass('like').removeClass('unlike');
        }

    });

    })

    });

    </script>
```

And I m not getting any response but when i use

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".like").click(function(){

    var postId = $(this).attr('id');

    var postData = 'postid='+postId+'&uid=<?php echo $id ?>';

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "like_notes",
        data: postData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(){

            $('#'+postId).text('UnLike').addClass('unlike').removeClass('like');
        }

    });

})


$(".unlike").click(function(){

    var postId = $(this).attr('id');

    var postData = 'postid='+postId+'&uid=<?php echo $id ?>';

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "likeun_notes",
        data: postData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(){

            $('#'+postId).text('Like').addClass('like').removeClass('unlike');
        }

    });

})

});

</script>

only once it is changing the value
```

Comment: you have variables `$pid` and `$lid`, but you use `$id` and `$lid` in query. typo?

Comment: $pid i m using for another function....

Comment: ok, then I guess `$id` is defined somewhere else?

Comment: yes that is comming from session

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the second version works only once, because at the beginning, the event is on the button, then you re-render the button by changing it's class and text, so the events get unbinded.

Same is for the 1st version. Jquery says: **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()....  If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page.**

So re-bind the events after changing the button.

I suggest something like this:

```
function bindEvents() {
    $('.like').off().on('click', function(){
        var postId = $(this).attr('id');

        var postData = 'postid='+postId+'&uid=' + <?php echo $id ?>;

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "like_notes",
            data: postData,
            cache: false,
            success: function(){

            $('#'+postId).text('UnLike').addClass('unlike').removeClass('like');
           //rebind events here
           bindEvents();
        }
    });
     $('.unlike').off().on('click', function(){
        var postId = $(this).attr('id');

        var postData = 'postid='+postId+'&uid=' + <?php echo $id ?>;

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "likeun_notes",
            data: postData,
            cache: false,
            success: function(){

            $('#'+postId).text('Like').addClass('like').removeClass('unlike');
           //rebind events here
           bindEvents();
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    bindEvents();
});
```

Also notice that in `var postData = 'postid='+postId+'&uid=<?php echo $id ?>';` code, the php part won't be treated as php. It will be just a string. So replace that part with the following, assuming that the code is located inside a php file:

```
var postData = 'postid='+postId+'&uid=' + <?php echo $id ?>;
```

Comment: the front-end part works as it should: http://jsfiddle.net/ar99tetm/
So it's something in backend. Does the request get sent? What's the response?

Comment: By the way in `var postData = 'postid='+postId+'&uid=<?php echo $id ?>';` the `postid` will be equal to exactly `'&uid=<?php echo $id ?>'`, I fixed that part also.